# How to import and export methods and libraries defined in one js file to the other js file in react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My problem is, I have a js file having a functionality of opening a tab-bar on clicking. Here is the link of that js file https://jsfiddle.net/6719phr3/1/

I want the same feature of opening a tab-bar to be used in the other js file as well without adding the methods and functionalities again in that js file. The Code is here.

```
import React, { useState,useCallback } from "react";
import {Card,CardGroup,Badge} from 'react-bootstrap';

const Health_status = (props) => {
return (
<CardGroup>
<Card className="cards">

<Card.Body>
  <Card.Title>Cluster-1 [ID]</Card.Title>
  <Card.Text>
  
  </Card.Text>
</Card.Body>

  <Card border="secondary" style={{ width: '18rem' }} className ="sub-cards-rec">
  <Card.Header>Recording Unit [ID]</Card.Header>
  <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>[ID]</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>
      <h6 onClick{()=>openPane()}><Badge pill bg="primary" >Cumulative Data Rate:{}</Badge></h6>
      
    {css ? (<h6 onClick={toggle2}><Badge pill bg="success" >Cumulative Sensor Status:{}</Badge></h6>)
      :(<h6 onClick={toggle2}><Badge pill bg="danger" >Cumulative Sensor Status:{}</Badge></h6>)
      }
    </Card.Text>
  </Card.Body>
  </Card><br />
  <Card border="secondary" style={{ width: '18rem' }} className ="sub-cards-ana">
  <Card.Header>Analysis Unit [ID]</Card.Header>
  <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>[ID]</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>
    <h6><Badge pill bg="warning" >Instance-Number:{}</Badge></h6>
    </Card.Text>
  </Card.Body>
  </Card><br />
  </Card>
  </CardGroup>

  }
  export default Health_status;
```

So I want to add a tabbar on clicking <Card.Text> Cumulative Data Rate from the above given code. How to export and import the methods and libraries from the first js file to this js file.

Comment: It depends on where this other file, or more accurately, other component is. If it's a child of `<Health_status />`, you can pass the `openPane` method as a prop. If it's in a completely different place, you can use Context by moving the tabs state into the Context and exposing a function to add / remove / show / hide tabs. If you can create a codesandbox with the minimal code to reflect your case, I can try to help further.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-glitter-nl1wp?file=/src/Navbar.js

Comment: Do check I have attached the full functional code.

Comment: Could you please check the code that I have added in the comment section.

Comment: Sorry, the codesandbox is not actually working (a log of missing components and styles) :| I tried to fix it a bit but seems like fixing it requires more time than I have. Can you fix it and make it way simpler? Just create a simple component with Tabs and different components that are using it.